# How do I recognize mouse clicks in Scala?

Tags: scala, double-click

I'm writing a small GUI program. Everything works except that I want to recognize mouse double-clicks. However, I can't recognize mouse clicks (as such) at all, though I can click buttons and select code from a list.

The following code is adapted from Ingo Maier's "The scala.swing package":

```
import scala.swing._
import scala.swing.event._

object MouseTest extends SimpleGUIApplication {
  def top = new MainFrame {
    listenTo(this.mouse) // value mouse is not a member of scala.swing.MainFrame
    reactions += {
      case e: MouseClicked =>
        println("Mouse clicked at " + e.point)
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried multiple variations: mouse vs. Mouse, SimpleSwingApplication, importing MouseEvent from java.awt.event, etc. The error message is clear enough--no value mouse in MainFrame--so, where is it then? Help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe that way?

```
object App extends SimpleSwingApplication {
  lazy val ui = new Panel {
    listenTo(mouse.clicks)
    reactions += {
      case e: MouseClicked =>
        println("Mouse clicked at " + e.point)
    }
  }
  def top = new MainFrame {
    contents = ui
  }
}
```

BTW, `SimpleGUIApplication` is deprecated

Comment: Yes, that works--thanks!

To summarize: 'mouse' is defined in Component. A Panel is a kind of Component, so mouse clicks can be recognized in a Panel. A MainFrame is not a subclass of Component (nor is Frame), so mouse clicks cannot be recognized directly in a MainFrame; it must contain a Panel.

I'm still not clear why "case MouseClicked(`myListView`)" is illegal, since a ListView is a component, but I can probably get double-clicking on a ListView element to work now.

Answer (score 1):

The [MouseClicked](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/swing/event/MouseClicked.html#clicks%3aInt) event has an attribute `clicks`, which should be `2` if it was a double-click.  Have a look at [java.awt.event.MouseEvent](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html) for the original source if you're curious.